# Does Common Lisp have a something like java's Set Interface/implementing classes?

Tags: java, lisp, set, sbcl

I need something like [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), a collection of elements which contains no duplicates of any element. Does Common Lisp, specifically SBCL, have any thing like this?

Answer (score 7):

Look at [cl-containers](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-containers/). There is a set-container class.

Answer (score 6):

For a quick solution, just use hash tables, as has been mentioned before.

However, if you prefer a more principled approach, you can take a look at [FSet](http://common-lisp.net/project/fset/), which is “a functional set-theoretic collections library”.  Among others, it contains classes and operations for sets and bags.

(EDIT:) The cleanest way would probably be to define your set-oriented operations as generic functions.  A set of generic functions is basically equivalent to a Java interface, after all.  You can simply implement methods on the standard HASH-TABLE class as a first prototype and allow other implementations as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it has sets. See [this section on "Sets"](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-lists-other-uses-for-cons-cells.html) from *Practical Common Lisp*.

Basically, you can create a set with `pushnew` and `adjoin`, query it with `member`, `member-if` and `member-if-not`, and combine it with other sets with functions like `intersection`, `union`, `set-difference`, `set-exclusive-or` and `subsetp`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use lists, though they can prove to be inefficient for representing large sets.  This is done using ADJOIN or [PUSHNEW](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pshnew.htm) to add a new element to a list, and [DELETE or REMOVE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) to do the opposite.

```
(let ((set (list)))
  (pushnew 11 set)
  (pushnew 42 set)
  (pushnew 11 set) 
  (print set) ; set={42,11}
  (setq set (delete 42 set))
  (print set)) ; set={11}
```

One thing to watch out for is all that these operators use [EQL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm) by default to test for potential duplicates in the set (much as Java uses the equals method). That's OK for sets holding numbers or characters, but for sets of other objects, a `deeper' equality test such as [EQUAL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm) should be specified as a :TEST keyword parameter, e.g. for a set of strings :-

```
(let ((set (list)))
  (pushnew "foo" set :test #'equal)
  (pushnew "bar" set :test #'equal)
  (pushnew "foo" set :test #'equal) ; EQUAL decides that "foo"="foo"
  (print set)) ; set={"bar","foo"}
```

Lisp's counterparts to some of Java's Set operations are:

- addAll -> [UNION or NUNION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_unionc.htm)
- containsAll -> [SUBSETP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subset.htm#subsetp)
- removeAll -> [SET-DIFFERENCE or NSET-DIFFERENCE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_di.htm)
- retainAll -> [INTERSECTION or NINTERSECTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_isec_.htm#intersection)

Comment: This is a recommended approach to start with then optimise later should profiling suggest it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Easily solvable using a hash table.

```
(let ((h (make-hash-table :test 'equalp))) ; if you're storing symbols
  (loop for i from 0 upto 20
        do (setf (gethash i h) (format nil "Value ~A" i)))
  (loop for i from 10 upto 30
        do (setf (gethash i h) (format nil "~A eulaV" i)))
  (loop for k being the hash-keys of h using (hash-value v)
        do (format t "~A => ~A~%" k v)))
```

outputs

```
0 => Value 0
1 => Value 1
...
9 => Value 9
10 => 10 eulaV
11 => 11 eulaV
...
29 => 29 eulaV
30 => 30 eulaV
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but you can use [hash tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_.htm) for something quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Lisp hashtables are CLOS based. Specs [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_hash_t.htm).

Comment: Umm...  CL's standard hash tables _are_ instances of the CLOS class HASH-TABLE, which you can define methods for without worries.  Furthermore, the article you link to talks about a kind of object system that isn't like CLOS at all.  In CLOS, methods belong to generic functions, not objects.

Comment: Common Lisp hashtables are wrapped in CLOS.  I don't know in what sense they're "CLOS based".  CLTL1 had hashtables but no CLOS, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just implement a function which takes a list and return a unique set. I've drafted something together which works for me:

```
(defun make-set (list-in &optional (list-out '()))
  (if (endp list-in)
      (nreverse list-out)
      (make-set
        (cdr list-in)
        (adjoin (car list-in) list-out :test 'equal))))
```

Basically, the `adjoin` function prepends an item to a list non-destructively if and only if the item is not already present in the list, accepting an optional test function (one of the Common Lisp "equal" functions). You can also use `pushnew` to do so destructively, but I find the tail-recursive implementation to be far more elegant. So, Lisp does export several basic functions that allow you to use a list as a set; no built-in datatype is needed because you can just use different functions for prepending things to a list.

My data source for all of this (not the function, but the info) has been a combination of the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/common-lisp.html) and [Common Lisp the Language (2nd Edition)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/cltl2.html).