# Set, not list in Lisp world?

Tags: lisp, set-theory

In set theory, we have `{x, y, z}`, which is the same as `{z, y, x}` which is the same as ... `{y, x, z}`, `{z, x, y}` ... Now, in Lisp (Scheme etc.) a list doesn't allow such juxtaposition. Order matters. Question: Is there a Lisp/Scheme equivalent to an order-doesn't-matter set?

Just guessing, I might simply construct a list, say `(x y z)`, then have some sort of `member?` i.e., *Are you a member of?* mechanism.

...I bet I'm not the only person who's wondered about this...

Comment: [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) has some set operations for lists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/165767/1116364

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This is a deeper question about the nature and theory of Lisp, not about Common Lisp or "sets" as a data structure.

Comment: @Rei "Is there a Lisp/Scheme equivalent to an order-doesn't-matter set?" That being IMO the main question here, I surely think that this is a duplicate. The question is about having/using sets *in* Lisp (though not specified which, as such, it would be too broad). It's not about using sets *for* Lisp (i.e. as replacement as "fundamental data structure").

Comment: No, he refers to the mathematical meaning of the word "set". He thinks (correctly, perhaps naively) that lisp lists are ordered, i.e. a ordered set, so his question naturally follows: are lisp lists "sets" in the mathematical sense? if not, is there anything in lisp, as a language/notation that generalizes lists? Not an implementation, not a library.
From a mathematical point of view, this question makes sense; however, most programmers are so unaccustomed to mathematics that they fail to get the original meaning of the terms used in CS. So it's not a duplicate, it's a good theory question.

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about `common lisp`, it has a bunch of functions, which operate on lists like if they were sets:

`(member 'b '(a b c d))
=> (B C)`

You can also use `member_if`. There are also some other functions for set operations:

`(union '(a b c) '(f a d))
=> (C B F A D)`

`(intersection '(a b c) '(f a d))
=> (A)`

`(set-difference '(a b c) '(b c d))
=> (A)`